# 16.04 LTS kernel upgrade fails to update

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

My kernel in my 16.04 LTS installation doesn't seem to be upgrading.  It is  stuck at the 4.4.0-116 kernel I got when I initially upgraded to 16.04.

I thought 16.04.5 ahould have the 4.15 kernel.  Am I not getting the point releases (I thought I was supposed to get the point releases automatically)?

I've seen references to HWE for 16.04 kernel upgrades but I have no clue what this is or what it means.  It apparently has something to do with the X stack, which makes me nervous; kernel upgrades back when I was on 12.04 caused me X server crashes on boot up.  (This got fixed when I upgraded to 16.04.)

aptitude is not showing any kernel upgrades past 4.4.0-116.  What should I do to get kernel upgrades?

Comment: Note that HWE will (eventually) include both Bionic’s default kernel and Bionic’s X. You can undo the package installation and then `apt autoremove` in a TTY (press Ctrl+Alt+F3) if that causes issues.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic\*`? Thanks.